# what is the complexity of this power() function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

It is algorithm to find the power of a given number. How will the statements after the recursion affect the complexity if at all?

```
int power(int b, int n){
 if (n == 0)
    return 1;
 else {
    int p = power(b, n/2);
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
        return p * p;
    else 
        return b * p * p;
 }
}
```

Comment: Multiplication is usually assumed to be constant. The complexity is logarithmic with respect to the value, or linear in the length of the input = number of bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As, you're dividing `n` by `2` at each step, the algorithm runs until `n` reaches to `0`. We can see what is happening:

```
n1 = n / 2
n2 = n1 / 2 = (n / 2) / 2 = n / 4 = n / (2^2)
n3 = n2 / 2 = n / 8 = n / (2^3)
...
...
```

It runs as long as `n >= (2^x)`, where `x` is any non-negative integer.

So, we can say that, when `2^x > n`, it stops(where `x` is the minimum possible integer, for which `2^x > n`).

Now, we may write

```
2^k = n, // where k is a non-negative integer
or, lg(2^k) = lg(n) // here, 'lg' means 2-based log
or, k = lg(n)
```

So, the minimum possible value of `x(for which it stops running)` would be `k + e, where e is a very small number`, but of course, we're considering `integer here(cause, no of steps)`. So, we could just write `x = k + 1`.

So, the number of steps the algorithm runs is `x`(considering, multiplication's complexity constant) which is equal to `k + 1` or `lg(n) + 1`.

So, it is `O(lg(n) + 1)` or, we may say, `O(lg(n))`.

Comment: Big thanks for such a detailed explanation :D cheers!!